# Meteor deploy to a device: how to configure the starting url?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

My app have two parts, 'localhost:8000/' is the default, i.e., web part.

Another part is 'localhost:8000/mobile', which is for the mobile use case.

Now I am ready to deploy the 'mobile' app to ios device, but I don't want the ios app starts with localhost:8000/. I want it start with localhost:8000/mobile

I have tried point to /mobile dynamically like this(in the starting code):

`if Meteor.isCordova(){
  location.href='/mobile'
}`

This works logically. However, every time I open the app, it load the default page('/'), and then reload the page('/mobile').

Is it possible to accomplish this via some configuration?

i.e. is it possible to configure the "starting url" for deployed mobile app?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. Are you asking about deep linking?

Comment: My app have two parts, 'localhost:8000/' is the default, i.e., web part.

Another part is 'localhost:8000/mobile', which is for the mobile use case.

I want to deploy the app to ios device, but I don't want the ios app start by visiting localhost:8000/. I want it start from localhost:8000/mobile

Comment: Please rework your question. I don't believe anyone knows what you're talking about.

Comment: OK, I have done editing.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently doing a conditional *routing* (via redirection).

You could try instead a conditional *rendering*: you would have a single starting page, and you would render a different layout depending on the result of `Meteor.isCordova`